# react native : there is way to fix the error "Animated event must have event data" in react tab navigation 5?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-navigation

I get "Animated event must have event data" error every time I move the tabs and I really do not understand what caused it and why.
I would be happy to get some help with this.
I have created 3 tabs and every time i move between them it gives me this error. I don't know how to solve it .
what is the reason for this error ? why is it happening in my case ?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import { useRoute, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function NetuneyDigum() {
  return (
    <>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          backgroundColor: '#cbced4',
        }}
      >
        <Text>NetuneyDigum!</Text>
      </View>
    </>
  );
}

function BdikotSadea() {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#cbced4',
      }}
    >
      <Text>BdikotSadea!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
function E_BitsuaDigdum() {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#cbced4',
      }}
    >
      <Text>E_BitsuaDigdum!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

export default function Screen8() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const route = useRoute();
  const params = route.params;
  const { item } = params;
  console.log('screen 8: ', params);
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: '#275d9f',
        inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        indicatorStyle: {
          backgroundColor: 'red',
        },
        style: {
          //   backgroundColor: '#8bb8ef',
        },
        labelStyle: {
          fontSize: 18,
          fontWeight: 'bold',
         
        },
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen name="one" component={NetuneyDigum} />
      <Tab.Screen name="two" component={BdikotSadea} />
      <Tab.Screen name="three" component={E_BitsuaDigdum} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you try re-building your app . This happened to me and I just rebuilt my app and it was gone. Try that it may be a bug

Comment: its not works..the error gone only if i dont allow swiping to the sides . there is a bug with this issue and no one can solve it ,